# ansible shell module fails to run sed for string insert operation

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to insert a string in `docker.conf` file and it is failing on ansible may be due to my syntax. Works when I do it manually.

vars:

```
memlock_value: "16777216:16777216"
docker_options_file: "/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf"
```

The task is

```
     - name: "Set in flag for ulimit in docker conf"
       shell: |
         - "sed '/^Environment=/ s/\"$/ --default-ulimit memlock={{ memlock_value }}\"/' {{ docker_options_file }} -i"
```

output:

```
 task path: /ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave1/workspace/teamd/run_ansible_playbook/k8s/baremetal/roles/team-node-config/tasks/main.yml
23:27:53  Tuesday 07 December 2021  07:27:53 +0000 (0:00:11.047)       0:00:19.487 ****** 
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "- \"sed '/^Environment=/ s/\\\"$/ --default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216\\\"/' /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf -i\"\n    \n", "delta": "0:00:00.004384", "end": "2021-12-07 07:27:53.586179", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2021-12-07 07:27:53.581795", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option - ", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option - "], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The manual command works:

```
sed '/^Environment=/ s/"$/ --default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216"/' /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf -i
```

I also tried lineinefile but it replaces the whole line instead of just inserting at end

```
    - name: "Set in flag for ulimit in docker conf"
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ docker_options_file_dummy }}"
        regexp: '^Environment='
        insertafter: '^Environment=.+$'
        line: "--default-ulimit memlock={{ memlock_value }}"
      ignore_errors: yes
```

output

```
=> {"backup": "", "changed": true, "msg": "line replaced"}
```

```
[Service]
--default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216
```

Comment: remove `"` qoutes. Remove `-`

Comment: that worked. nice. but i did not had to quote the {{ }}. is it good practice to quote?

Comment: It's bad practice to use shell in the first place. I think it would be good to qoute, something like `{{ "'" + var | replace("'", "'\''") + "'" }}`, but really, if you have control over input you can just add quotes in front and the end. For example when `memlock_value` will have `/` character, then `sed` will fail anyway... there are many corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to figure out here it is but am still trying to figure out how to make it idempotent. multiple runs is keeping on adding the content at end of line.

```
    - name: "add ulimit in tests file to end of line in {{ dummy_file }}"
      lineinfile:
        dest: "{{ dummy_file }}"
        state: present
        regexp: '^(Environment="[^"]*)'
        backrefs: yes
        line: '\1 {{ ulimit_memlock_flag }}"'
```

file before task

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=  --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --iptables=false"
```

file after task

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=  --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --iptables=false --default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to figure out here it is with idempotency. multiple runs does not add the content at end of line again.

```
    - name: "with idempotency add ulimit in tests file to end of line in {{ dummy_file }}"
      lineinfile:
        dest: "{{ dummy_file }}"
        state: present
        #regexp: '^(DOCKER_OPTS="[^"]*)'
        regexp: (.*"DOCKER_OPTS=.*iptables=false)
        backrefs: yes
        line: '\1 {{ ulimit_memlock_flag }}"'
```

file before task

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=  --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --iptables=false"
```

file after task run 1

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=  --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --iptables=false --default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216"
```

file after task run 2

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=  --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --iptables=false --default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216"
```

Answer (score -1):

The literal text inside `|` block is not an array. Also, remove global `"` quotes - a command is not a single command but is split on spaces, so spaces have to be there.

Try:

```
   shell: |
     sed "'/^Environment=/ s/\"$/ --default-ulimit memlock={{ memlock_value }}\"/'" "{{ docker_options_file }}" -i
```

It's odd that `-i` option is on the end. I think It would be nicer to:

```
   shell: <
     sed -i -e
     "'/^Environment=/ s/\"$/ --default-ulimit memlock={{ memlock_value }}\"/'
     "{{ docker_options_file }}"
```

You should prefer `command` over `shell`

```
   command:
     argv:
       - sed
       - -i
       - -e
       - '/^Environment=/ s/"$/ --default-ulimit memlock={{ memlock_value }}"/'
       - "{{ docker_options_file }}"
```

And, you should prefer `lininfile` over `sed`. Something along:

```
 lineinfile:
    regexp: '^(Environment=[^"]*)"'
    backrefs: yes
    line: '\1  --default-ulimit memlock={{ memlock_value }}"'
    path: "{{ docker_options_file }}"
```

Comment: lineInfile failed `{"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (lineinfile) module: file Supported parameters include: attributes, backrefs, backup, content, create, delimiter, directory_mode, firstmatch, follow, force, group, insertafter, insertbefore, line, mode, owner, path, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, state, unsafe_writes, validate"}`

Comment: yea will do but I have to inform too right? btw command worked. so please strip off all options and keep command solution I will mark answer. thanks for help

Comment: i tried but it is replace the whole line and not inserting. not sure what am  i missing. `[Service]
--default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216`